# When saving files to the desktop, how can I control which side of the screen they default to?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons

I'm a Mac user at home, new Linux user at work. I'm trying to do my best to get my Dell laptop running Ubuntu to behave like my Mac wherever possible.

One small, but annoying thing is that files save to the left side of my screen by default. I've got all my windows positioned to leave about an inch of space on the right side of my screen so that I can quickly access a few common files and folders.

I'd like to know if there's a way to automatically have newly created files positioned to the right side of the screen.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Firstly I'd try and be precise on details, there is no Ubuntu 18.  Ubuntu uses the *yy.mm* format for all server & desktop releases (which have multiple releases per year and are *deb* based), and *yy* only for specialist (*snap* based) releases for devices (such as Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances).  My guess is you're not talking about an IoT appliance at work?  (Ubuntu Core 18 doesn't have a GUI as doesn't make sense on headless appliances). If you want common items on the right, why not use a dock there with what you want? (*assuming it's a deb based yy.mm system you're talking about*)

Comment: I clarified my version, and the machine I'm using.

Comment: Side note the dock on the right isn't a bad idea, but one of my main reasons for wanting files on the right is because I write to my desktop constantly. I save screenshots and temp scripts that I use, then throw away. So if I could write to "the dock" and achieve that functionality then that would work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible and quite ugly workaround would be to keep creating / copying dummy files or folders in the desktop to saturate all but the "*right side*" of the screen (maybe leaving out one or two rightmost columns). Then your newly created useful files and folders would start occupying the right side.

Also if those *few common files and folders* that you  want to access easily are unchanging, then you can simply drag and drop them to the right end of your desktop manually.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid an ugly hack. I know some people avoid using their desktop for anything and that's their preference. I like having a handful of commonly accessed files there for quick reference. I also save screenshots and temp scripts there for easy access. I like how you're thinking though, thanks.